# Writing a function to set up and solve the least squares problem

Tags: fitting, linear-algebra, homework, approximation

I have setup the explicit line equation for a given set of points using least-squares approximation and the knots computed below. I have tried extending the same code for use with an arbitrary degree, say 5, or for any degree I give. I want to set up the normal equations and then use `LinearSolve`. I am stuck and unable to find a solution.

```
(* input data    Number of points is actually m+1 *)
m = 30;
data1 = Table[{t, Sqrt[t] + 0.4 RandomReal[]}, {t, 0.0, 10.0, 10/m}];
data2 = Table[{t + RandomReal[{-0.25, 0.25}], 
Cos[t] + RandomReal[{-0.25,     0.25}]}, {t, 0.0, 10.0, 10/m}];
data2 = {{0, 0}, {0.3, 0},(*{0.4,1},*){1, 1}};
data = data1;
m = Length[data] - 1;
(* Parametric line equation     line(t) = (1-t)b_0 + t*b_1 *)
(* For each data_i, associate a parameter value knot_i (increasing \
values) *)
(* Find b_0 and b_1 to minimize error in ||line(t_i) - data_i|| *)

(* create knots for parametric form *)
knot = Table[t, {t, 0.0, 1.0, 1/m}];
(* degree 1 *)
n = 1; 
vandermonde = Table[BernsteinBasis[n, j - 1, knot[[i]]], {i, 1, m + 1}, {j,1,n + 1}];
bez = LinearSolve[Transpose[vandermonde].vandermonde, 
Transpose[vandermonde].data];
bezpolyplot = ListLinePlot[bez, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thin}];
```

Comment: Have you seen `LeastSquares[]`?

Comment: we have to implement it without using least squares....it should be similar to the one above..using knots and the bernstein basis function